# Forall syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, cplex, forall

I am trying to write the following code but it gives me "syntax error, unexpected forall".

How do I fix this?

```
maximize sum(i in cargos, j in comps) profit[i]*x[i][j];

subject to {
cons01
    forall(i in cargos)
      available_wight:
        sum(j in comps) x[i][j] <= weight[i];

cons02:
    forall (j in comps)
      weight_capacity:
        sum(i in cargos)x[i][j] <= weight_cap[j];

cons03;
    forall (j in comps)
      space_capacity;
        sum(i in cargos)valume[i]*x[i][j] <= space_cap[j];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

> cons01

`available_wight:` is the label of the constraint.